# WCF contract mismatch error only when running in parallel

Tags: wcf, task-parallel-library

I have a load tester that calls my WCF service and I've built it with options to run the calls in parallel or not. Only when running in parallel, I get the following error for all threads: "The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."

This is more or less my code:

```
            if (runMultiThreaded)
            {
                ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
                options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
                ParallelLoopResult loopResult = Parallel.For(0, numberOfTimesToTest, options,
                    (i, loopState) =>
                    {
                        myService.MyOperation();
                        if (loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration) return;
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < test1NumberOfRuns; i++)
                {
                        myService.MyOperation();
                }
            }
```

Any ideas? Let me know if you need more details.

UPDATE: myService is an instance of my service's operation contract interface that was created with a ChannelFactory using the CreateChannel method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your `myService` is a `ClientBase<T>` subclass or a channel created explicitly via `ChannelFactory<T>::CreateChannel`? If so those instances are not guaranteed to be thread safe and you so you need an instance per worker thread.

Comment: It is a channel created via a ChannelFactory, so that would explain it, thank you. Are there any ways of doing this with something that is thread safe so that I don't have to create an instance for every thread? Creating that instance for every thread is quite slow...

Comment: Hmmm... CreateChannel should be one of the faster operations in WCF land. Conversely ChannelFactory creation is usually one of the slowest things you can do. Are you using sessions on the service you're talking to? What about authentication? That could obviously impact newly created channels too.

Comment: My routine to create the channel using a channel factory also uses the OperationContext to add headers that will pass on an authentication token. I am not sure how much impact that causes, but I can't work around that, the token needs to be in the header otherwise the service won't work.